# Reading exif data of .txt files

Tags: ctf

Our university organizes a CTF competition every year. This year in the field of forensics, the task was to find the metadata hidden in the .txt file. exiftool, which I usually use did not return any results. Does anyone have any suggesstion of which tool I could use?

Comment: AFAIK, a text file doesn't contain other metadata besides the usual file system information (owner, created and modified timestamps, group, size, name, etc). EXIF is used in image/media files.

Comment: @gru Yeah that's what i was assuming but inside the file this is the text: _Steganography is the‌‌‌‌‍‬‌ practice ‌‌‌‌‍‍‌of ‌‌‌‌‍‬‍‬hiding a secret‌‌‌‌‍‬ message ‌‌‌‌‍‌‬‍inside of (or even on top of) something that‌‌‌‌‍‬‬ is not‌‌‌‌‍‍‌ secret. In ‌‌‌‌‌‌this case‌‌‌‌‍‍ message is hidden in this simple .txt file alone. :) Can you find it?_